# Get Age of a person in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can i get a Persons age in mysql

Imagine i have a table with `member.id, member.month, member.year`
Now i need to get age of a member in **Months**.

Say:

```
member.month = 1 and member.year = 2000
```

That would mean the age of this member is **126** because **10** Years equals **120** Months and **6** Months is **6** Months. 
Now the result is that the members age is **126** Month.

How can i do it in MySql

Comment: why are you storing month/year as individual fields instead of as a date field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select YEAR(NOW())*12+MONTH(NOW()) - (member.year*12+member.month) +1;
```

To make my answer yield 126, I had to add 1 to the expression. I'm not sure that makes sense, but it just depends on how you want to define age.

Comment: This works but it still seems awfully silly to store date info this way.

Comment: @Erik: To play devil's advocate here, what he's storing *isn't* a date. If all he's interested in is year and month, then storing a specific day (even if you standardized on the first day of the month) would be adding illegitimate precision.

Answer (score 2):

1. it shouldn't be separate fields, it must be one  field of `date` type.
2. mysql has good date calculations example page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-calculations.html
   first one is yours

Comment: While I'd generally agree that it should be a `Date`, there's no technical reason why it "must be". A better tack to take would be to, like Erik, ask why he's doing that.

Comment: I did. He responded with "I was drunk"